# Ubuntu on WSL doesn't launch

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 for windows subsystem for linux on windows 10, after enabling WSL in Powershell (instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10).

I've done this before on a desktop but now I'm doing it on a laptop. I had no issues with the previous installation but this time around ubuntu will not launch. I get the ubuntu console popping up briefly before disappearing.

Also trying to run bash.exe from the command line fails silently (doesn't hang, just exits with no message), which may be related.

I'm struggling to figure this out as I have no idea where any error messages might be logged. Does anyone know how I can investigate further why this is happening?

Setup is a windows 10 Pro, os build 17134.376, everything up to date.

Comment: Yes, should have said - Debian won't install, get's hung at "Installing, this may take a few minutes". OpenSUSE installs fine.

Comment: Also I've just discovered that Ubuntu 16.04 installs ok, it's just 18.04 which is having this issue

Comment: Can you collect log with [logon method](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#8-detailed-logs)?

Answer (score 3):

> I'm struggling to figure this out as I have no idea where any error messages might be logged. Does anyone know how I can investigate further why this is happening?

Check with `wslconfig.exe /l` all registered distros.

As a last resort, deregister the one you have problem and run the ubuntu.exe in your distro once again. Just a wild guess, it might be also a problem, if you have more than one copy of the linux distribution in you home directory.

> !!! Warning !!!
>
> Deregistering deletes all files!
> `wslconfig.exe /u Ubuntu`
>
> !!! Warning!!!

Comment: That deregister tip helped me. Thanks!

Comment: Note that /u (aka /unregister) deletes all the user files in your distro, which is not necessarily what you expect. A last resort.